# Scrape Website loaded with Ajax, using Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, ajax

I am looking to scrape a few websites such as Ubereats.com.au. Currently I am utilising Mechanize and Nokogiri to navigate the initial search form, however when the page loads all items are generated through Ajax. The website utilise a JSON request, however this is blocked from using from anywhere but the website origin. Could someone explain to me the best way to scrape this data, either by grabbing the JSON or utilising a tool such as a headless browser.

Comment: if you have a GUI than you don't need a headless environment. Otherwise the headless gem is pretty straightforward. Selenium is a good browser automation tool as is phantom. Look through a tutorial and post a new question if you have problems.

Comment: Can you explain how the ajax calls are restricted? Normally this can be checked only through cookies and the Referer header, but those one you can easily fake.

Comment: Hi Hakcho, the ajax is a back end api for a website and utilises tokens, hashes to restrict.

Comment: Thanks Max, Ill check out Selenium :)